# Error shutting down simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcrun, simctl

In `xcrun simctl` documentation there is an entry:

> **xcrun simctl shutdown booted** - Shutdown a device

Bun when I call it from command line, the simulator is not actually shut down but is freezed instead.

How this could be solved?

The only workaround I found is to kill the simulator by its *Process ID*.

```
killall "Simluator"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulator.app predates CoreSimulator and still assumes that it owns the entire boot lifecycle.  You should only use 'simctl shutdown' for devices that you booted via 'simctl boot'.

Comment: Could you give me an example how to properly launch Simulator using `simctl boot`?

Comment: Simulator.app will only work correctly with devices where it owns the lifecycle; we do not currently support mixing simctl boot / simctl shutdown and Simulator.app. Most other simctl commands work with a device started by Simulator.app.